# Php pdo SELECT statment not returning a value that i need

Tags: php, sql, function, pdo

I have a select statement that returns a user id:

```
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '" . $user_name . "'");   
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
```

This is working fine but when i call a function thats supposed to return the friend id: (The select statement)

```
function get_friend($friend_username){

#create the PDO object 
/**
 * Used to instanciate the host of the server
 * @var string
 */
    $hostname = 'localhost';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the username to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $username = 'ODBC';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the password to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $pass = "";
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the database name
 * @var string
 */
    $db_name = 'bloggie_db';
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name" , $username, $pass);

        #set PDO error mode to exception 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '" . $friend_username . "'"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $friend_id = $row['user_id'];   
        return $friend_id;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getTrace();
    }
    $dbh = null;
} //The whole get friend function
```

The function call:

```
        $friend_id = $this->get_friend($friend_user_name);
```

This does not return anything but if i replace $friend_user_name with the value thats in the database 'testing@bloggie.com', then the $friend_id is returned. Why is it that when i use a variable it doesnt return but when i use an actual value it does return.

Comment: When you enable pdo errors (`$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`) do you get any errors? Also, since you're using pdo anyways, it's recommended to use prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection and syntax errors.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with variable scope. Please show the whole function that call `$this->get_friend($friend_user_name)`.

Comment: Ive added the whole function in the question.

Comment: IN your first version you are using query,in your second prepare.Read the manual on how to use PDO  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php Prepare with string concatenation wont work

Comment: I changed it sorry. The first one still works with string concatenation.

Comment: try to return $friend_user_name as soon as you call the function, to see if it is actually populated. as some suggested, this may be a variable scope issue

Comment: What does `$e->getTrace();` give?

Comment: No when i echo it just before i call it in the function it is the correct value.

Comment: $e->getTrace() gives: Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Bloggie\Objects\SQL.php [line] => 483 [function] => execute [class] => PDOStatement [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Bloggie\SubPages\AddFriend.php [line] => 32 [function] => add_friend [class] => SQL [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => test@bloggie.com [1] => testing@bloggie.com ) ) )

Comment: $friend_user_name is not out of its variable scope.

Comment: $user = "username";
$uid = get_friend($user);
echo "uid=".$uid; use this. it may be work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. By sending the friend id through an anchor tag to the page where the function is called worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.